# Deploying a Symfony2 project

Tags: php, deployment, symfony, hosting

We were working on a Symfony2 project. Now, it's done and ready to be deployed. We uploaded the whole project files to the server  (via ftp of course) and the database as well. Now when we open any page of it we got just a blank page (empty source code). Cache is clean, logs do not show anything new. We googled the steps of deploying a Symfony2 project to a hosting but we did not find a good explanation (even these ones were about Symfony not-version-2).
We believe it maybe a configuration issue, but no idea so far.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: the blank page is in Firefox. Google Chrome is saying something:

> Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://***.com/mammoky/web/app_dev.php/main. It may be down for
>   maintenance or configured incorrectly. Here are some suggestions:
>   Reload this webpage later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An
>   unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting
>   to fulfill the request.

error_log is showing:

> [24-Mar-2012 23:29:24] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected
>   T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in
>   /home/leadow33/public_html/mammoky/web/app.php on line 7

It's: use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
And

> [24-Mar-2012 23:15:08] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input: 
>   '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   /home/leadow33/public_html/mammoky/web/config.php on line 84

It's: $reflector = new \ReflectionExtension('intl');

---

**EDIT:** I've posted my solution, check it out down here.

Comment: Did you tried to use the app_dev.php ? what you get ? still blank ?

Comment: Yep, still blank.
I discovered in Chrome is showing this message:
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://*****.com/mammoky/web/app_dev.php/main. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
Does that make some sens?

Comment: Maybe the same with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417747/error-500-after-deploying-a-symfony-app

Comment: Not so much. Where to find this file: `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` ?

Comment: No I meant this (the answer) 'First the httpd.conf file MUST be changed to reference..' did you checked your httpd.conf or .htaccess BTW did you checked permissions ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Comment: OK, So that the problem is in the configuration, let focus on it.
I set the permission of app/log and app/cache to 777 but still get the same err of localhost restriction. I tried clearing the browsing cache by pressing Ctr+F5 but I'm still stack.

Comment: Judging by the exception the server does not have php5.3, but an older version instead. The requirement for Sf2 is 5.3.2.

Comment: @Maerlyn that's it, that's another problem, the hosting I'm deploying the project has 5.2. I emailed them so that they may give me another server with PHP 5.3. Thanks.

Comment: Until this one is resolved, any error message you get is caused by this, even if circumstances suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Nadj - thanks for posting your findings after discovering a solution. Bear in mind it's find to use the answer feature for this, even as a questioner - and it leaves your question intact for future readers.

Comment: "We uploaded the whole project ... (via ftp of course)" - if you can, move towards version control software for deployment, or failing that, `rsync` - either would make deploying much easier for you. FTP is not good way to deploy code changes.

Comment: Symfony2 is a professional framework, it is meant to be used on a VPS or a dedicated server with a SSH access. Deploying on a shared hosting using FTP will only result in future troubles and will just cost you more money in the long run.

Comment: @HubertPerron, alright, no problem, we just reserved a "starter" hosting for the test, our site's still on development phase . we'll move to a dedicated server having SSH access. Thanks a lot for the advice Hubert.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answer:

I got it to work, this is my experience:

- Upload the whole project folder to the server.
- Enter `www.your-website.com/project-name/web/config.php`.
- It should say: "This script is only accessible from localhost".
- Open this web site: http://www.whatismyip.com, it should show you your public IP address, copy it.
- Open the config.php from the admin panel (like cPanel) and edit that `config.php`:

---

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1', /*your IP here*/))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('This script is only accessible from localhost.');  
}
```

---

- Refresh your `config.php` file, the page will tell you if your system is missing some required conditions like: PHP version, APC extension, giving /cache and /log folders permissions to write on, etc.
- After you provide the required conditions you'll see a form of configuring you project to connect to a database if you have one, this step is pretty simple.
- Open the link `www.your-website.com/project-name/web/app_dev.php`, it'll help you get started with Symfony2 project.
- In case you got in `app_dev.php` this message: `You are not allowed to access this file...` just do the same thing to `app_dev.php` as you did in steps 4 and 5 (add your public IP address to the array).  
  Note of Hakan Deryal (comment): If you don't have a fix IP address, you need to do this last step each time you get a new IP adrdress from the DHCP. So to solve that, open the `app_dev.php` and comment out the line `die('You are not allowed to..`, however this is not a recommended way because you're disabling the built-in security of the file.
- One thing stopped me and may stop you too, the server I deployed the project on, was case-sensitive (unlike the localhost on my computer), so it kept telling me that the template (`Index.html.php` for example) does not exist, however it does exist, but I did `return $this->render('...:index.html.php')` with small `i` in `DefaultController.php`. So render the exact template (file) name with the same letters cases.

Now everything is going well, I hope that helps you.

Comment: That's not a good way to deploy an application. app_dev.php should only be used for development purposes, and should be disabled or protected in production environment due to security reasons. With the steps above, you are disabling the built-in security features, which may result in a compromised system.

Comment: Yes I confirm, it's not the best way, it's just the way I got it work , if you have a best alternative of some steps above then please post it. I'm just experiencing the thing I need an expert.

Comment: I think I solved the problem you talked about "disabling the built-in security features" of the file `app_dev.php` by adding the IP address to the array of "allowed accesses" in this file.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the php version* and I catched the error by running config.php with removed lines for checking ip address. On my hosting I just changed the default version of PHP for my scripts.

*Since namespaces are only from 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

production isnt app_dev but app.. The page might be the same did you do a view source? Did you try to run the config.php that comes with the framework zip ?

Comment: Source is also blank.
Running config.php (very good idea that I forgot about it) is saying: This script is only accessible from localhost.

Comment: @Nadj At the top of `config.php` you should have an array of allowed IP addresses. You could add yours temporarily there and reupload the file.

Comment: @jperovic, I did but still see the problem: This script is only accessible from localhost. So weird, this is the code:
`if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
    'my.ip.adr.ess',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}`

Comment: Weird indeed, cause I did this many times and it worked. Are you sure you put your public IP address? I use this service to find it: http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: Address of the website you mean? Yes it is, I'm already opening the CPanel through the address: my.ip.addr.ess:2082. am I right?

Comment: Hey @jperovic it really opened when I entered my personal IP, but .. I don't have a fixed one I think, I'm a DHCP client. I don't understand :?

Comment: Alright, I don't either but that one you were assigned from `DHCP` should last long enough for you to run `config.php` and and fix the bug :)

Comment: Yes that's great from you thanks dear. The config.php showed me some missing requirements from the hosted server, like version of PHP, apparently I must have PHP 5.3 to run Symfony2 project, however the current one has 5.2. I don't know, I remember I first created the project on my server with PHP 5.2 before I did an upgrade to 5.3. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your installation runs on a shared webserver, try setting the following line into the app.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

This solves the problem in my case.