# Steps to move Symfony 2 project to hosting?

Tags: symfony

I have read a lot of articles and questions about deploying of Symfony 2 project on a production server, but still, this is not clear. Deploy of Symfony project looks like a hell - nobody knows how to do this correctly. I suppose the best topic I see was [Deploying a Symfony2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855922/deploying-a-symfony2-project), but still, a lot isn`t clear. I read it, and find out that in that question person added his own IP to a list of allowed IP, but this means that only this IP can access this site, but I need to allow everybody use it.

And how can I make site working with path `www.mydomen.com`, instead of `www.mydomen.com/web/app_dev.php/index` (I can correct path via Symfony, but it works after `app_dev.php` and via hosting, but how can it work before /`app_dev.php`? It seems like app-dev.php should always be in my path).

So how should I correctly transfer developed project from local server to production server step by step, please?

Comment: This is how I do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887925/deploying-symfony-2-5-3-website-to-production-server

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK, I find out how to correctly deploy app on shared hosting. Here it is:

1. It depends on kind of hosting that you have: if you have SSH
   console, then you can do it on hosting after step 2, if you haven't
   then do it locally: run command `php app/console cache:clear
   --env=prod`.
2. Suppose you have on you hosting folders `youdomain/public_html`, so in
   `public_html` must be located all web files. You must upload all from Symfony project (folders: app, src, vendors, bin; files: deps, deps.lock), except folder `web` in folder `youdomain`. Everything from folder `web` should be upload to folder `public_html`.
3. Check CHMOD for folders app/cache and app/logs, there should be
   write access.
4. If there is no file `.htaccess` in `public_html`, then create it and add such code in it: https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/master/web/.htaccess
5. Now you should use `youdomain.com/index` instead of
   `youdomain.com/app_dev.php/index`, that you use locally.

If your site still did not works, you can open file `web/config.php` and find the code where the check for IP performed, you find there only IP 127.0.0.1, add your current IP to this list and upload new config on a server. Then you can open path `yourdomain/config.php` and check what's wrong. If `config.php` shows that everything ok, but your site still didn't work, you can enable `app_dev.php` to debug: open `app/app_dev.php` and add your IP to the list as for `config.php` done before. Now you can run scripts as locally using `app_dev.php`.

Comment: I did that, but I have got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/.../public_html/app.php on line 3. In this line is: use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;

Comment: It does not connect with deployment, seems to be some syntax error.

Comment: Symfony's web folder must exists. Instead of change web's folder name to public_html, it's better to make a symbolic link called public_html which will be pointing to web (public_html -> web). In other case, several commands will complain about missing web folder, e. g. assets:install.