# Symfony2 throws ContextErrorException after uploading the application to shared host

Tags: php, apache, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have so much problems with deploying Symfony2 project to server, with searching and help of some links like [Steps to move Symfony 2 project to hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462220/steps-to-move-symfony-2-project-to-hosting) I finally did something! the problem is when I go to mydomain.com/web/app.php it shows blank page! and when I go to mydomain.com/web/app_dev.php it throws this exception:

ContextErrorException: Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventSubscriberInterface.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php line 80

The project works completely right on my local machine. Please help me with some advice, thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy your symfony project on a shared hosting server? Do you have access to the path `/var/www/Symfony` in your hosted machine? are your symfony files in this directory or in `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/`?

Comment: yes I want to deploy it to shared server like a website, /var/www/Symfony is the path for my localhost on my linux os,I uploaded Symfony files to /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/ on server, it has not any ssh access, and really don't know what to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting in your PHP configuration. Turning it off should resolve your issue.

> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified
>   directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT
>   affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
>
> When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using
>   include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the
>   file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to
>   access it. All symbolic links are resolved, so it's not possible to
>   avoid this restriction with a symlink. If the file doesn't exist then
>   the symlink couldn't be resolved and the filename is compared to (a
>   resolved) open_basedir .

Comment: How can I access this PHP configuration, sry I'm kinda noob to the whole LAMP world.

Comment: The problem was open_basedir ,It's now Working, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

try clearing the cache, in the shared host delete everything inside the

```
app/cache
```

folder.