# Deploying Symfony 2.5.3 website to production server

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.5

I have been working on a website in development environment built on top of Symfony framework and now it is time to deploy it to live site, in development environment we run the command `php app/console server:run` to run the website but I am not sure what needs to be done to make the user see website contents on live server, after i uploaded the code to live server all I see is root directory structure of Symfony, I have gone through [How to Deploy a Symfony Application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) and i am scratching my head as there is got to be more to it because after following the steps no difference was made and i still see directory structure.

I did notice that when I click on the web folder I see the website so I created the following `.htaccess` file which works but the URL looks like `www.domain.com/web` how can i just make it `www.domain.com`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I will really appreciate if I can get some help here, if it helps I am trying to deploy on Linux based server using Apache.

**SOLUTION**
Add the following in your `.htaccess` file and it will work as this is what solved my problem and please remember to clear your browser cache as well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: One better solution is to say your web host to give path of DocumentRoot up to web.

Comment: imagine if you want to create a script to sell it, how on earth people without this kind of knowledge will be able to use the script?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462220/steps-to-move-symfony-2-project-to-hosting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following all the [How to deploy a Symfony App](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html), in the root of your Symfony application create `.htaccess` file and add the following code in it, this is what solved my problem.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running ubuntu do the following

```
  sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

change document root to and save

```
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
```

Then run

```
  sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then run

```
 cd /var/www/html

 php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

all done

Comment: what if you are on shared hosting and no access to apache configuration file?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done with htacess as I have never tried, but if I was to write something it may look like this 
     
`RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
     RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]`

Comment: what is this going to do?

Comment: domain-name.com - Type your own domain name
folder - Type the name of the sub-folder which has the web directory i.e. !web/ it is an attempt to rewrite the base url request to the web directory.

Comment: like i mentioned in my question that i am able to get the site to work with `.htaccess` by pointing it to the `web` folder except that now each URL has the word `web` in it like www.domain.com/web/about www.domain.com/web/services and so on

Comment: Then i think your stuck, honestly using Symfony framework it is recommended to use a hosting provider with ssh access, check out AWS at the moment you can get 12 months free access

Comment: nope not stuck, the `.htaccess` did the trick, this is what i have in my `.htaccess` file and it works like a charm, there is no mention of `web` folder in all URLs `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it is done professionally because I don't use symfony, but I will tell you how I did it when I was testing on Linux.

Let's say you have your `www` directory in `/home/user/www/` (it doesn't really matter). I would put whole symfony directory (with all directory structure) to some other directory (let's say `/home/user/applications/my-symfony-webpage` - the last being your directory with symfony files structure).

Last thing you need to do to make it work is to create a symlink which will direct from `/home/user/www/` to `/home/user/applications/my-symfony-webpage/web`.

It can be done with this command: `ln -s /home/user/applications/my-symfony-webpage/web /home/user/www/` (I think you need to delete www directory first if it's meant just for symfony installation).

That's my solution, I doubt it's the only one and probably not the best one. I think you can create redirects with apache to direct some domains to some directory in your file structure (in your case to `web` directory of course). You can look it up online.

Comment: Thanks for giving me your point of view, i have updated my question, i have mentioned that the site is working when i add `.htaccess` file and redirect to `web` folder but the domain looks like `domain.com/web` and all links look like `domain.com/web/about` and so on. The website is in root `public_html` and not in subfolder, just mentioning it in case

Comment: What I said would put symfony in your domain.com (no `web` in address)

Comment: I am saying there is a `web` folder that comes with symfony, this is the folder that people need to access in order to view the site.

Comment: I know that, that's what I said. You can put symlink to your `web` folder in place of your `www` directory and the symfony will work this way: domain.com/app.php.

Comment: But if thats something you don't understand then just keep reading the official document for configuration.

Comment: I am not aware of what is `symlink` i need to search about it, but what you are saying, is that same as changing the default root document of a domain to `web`?

Comment: effect is the same, but it's not the same. symlink is symbolic link - it's kinda "like" shortcuts in windows. But it's generally better to change default root document of domain ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your Apache to point your project folder `web` as document root.

You can find information about to configure your server here: [Configuring a Web Server (The Symfony CookBook)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)

Comment: I think this cannot be done for people on shared hosting as hosting companies do not provide access to Apache configuration file

Comment: Some shared hostings let you configure a subdirectory of your public folder as the entry point.

In other case you can try with the `.htaccess` configuration. As a start point you can take a look here: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html . You can use Silex with `web` directory and you can see a note about configure it with a directory that it is not the webroot.