# How to deploy Symfony3 App?

Tags: symfony

i created my first symfony App. It works on build in web server on a localhost. Then i copied all files to FTP but since that moment i have no idea what to do to make it run.

I read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/

Tried to configure http://deployer.org/ and Capistrano but its very hard for me to understand how should i make it going.

If someone could explain me steps to make my Symfony3 App Run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm freshly after installing symfony app to the production server, and hope my experience will help you.

## Instalation

The most basic installation consist of few points (just ordinary way):

**1. Copy symfony project to production server.**

**2. Composer install:**

```
$ composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

It modifies autoloader to fit the new environment and make all the magic under the hood.

*Tip: Start in shell with "export SYMFONY_ENV=prod" before to avert errors.*

**3. Clear and warm-up cache:**

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

It already works but under "/web" directory which is probably not what you want.

**4. Change the web server's document root (for example), and point it to `"/web"`.**

## End words

I'm keeping it straightforward, here are the sources:

- [Symfony's official deploy documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)
- [Useful case study on Ubuntu (with virtual host)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [4th step described - Apache's DocumentRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887925/deploying-symfony-2-5-3-website-to-production-server)

Comment: Why down vote? As I said, the intend was to keep it straightforward as possible in order to be easy to understand. At least inform what you are concerned about, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help but im still getting error 500. I managed to run it in dev mode but i cant run prod mode.

Comment: It might be tricky, you need to investigate "**prod.log**" file and "**error_log**" (one from Symfony, second from PHP). Without the error message I cannot help you, but you may always post in on StackOverflow if you are not sure what to do.