# How can I get my Symfony project to production mode?

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I hire a domain at a host company and I want to get my symfony project online.

I used the guide here to do it:
[Steps to move Symfony 2 project to hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462220/steps-to-move-symfony-2-project-to-hosting)

This gives me an 500 internal server error.
This is the first time I want to deploy a symfony project.

I want to get the project online at [stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl](http://stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl)

This is in the server error logs:

```
[Fri Nov 21 21:15:02 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/public_html/
[Fri Nov 21 21:15:02 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] File does not exist: /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/public_html/403.shtml
[Fri Nov 21 21:23:03 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/public_html/
[Fri Nov 21 21:23:03 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] File does not exist: /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/public_html/403.shtml
[Fri Nov 21 22:29:51 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 22:29:51 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 22:30:10 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 22:30:10 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 22:37:05 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 22:37:05 2014] [error] [client 84.198.13.59] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:16 2014] [error] [client 108.181.126.202] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071583/how-can-i-get-my-symfony-project-to-production-mode
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:16 2014] [error] [client 108.181.126.202] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071583/how-can-i-get-my-symfony-project-to-production-mode
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:16 2014] [error] [client 108.181.126.202] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:16 2014] [error] [client 108.181.126.202] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:16 2014] [error] [client 108.181.126.202] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:16 2014] [error] [client 108.181.126.202] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:25 2014] [error] [client 182.118.26.147] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/
[Fri Nov 21 23:42:25 2014] [error] [client 182.118.26.147] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/
[Sat Nov 22 13:45:28 2014] [error] [client 84.197.200.66] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat Nov 22 13:45:28 2014] [error] [client 84.197.200.66] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I renamed my web directory to public_html, when I try to acces the website now I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "C:/wamp/www/SocProNetbeans/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: fopen(C:/wamp/www/SocProNetbeans/app/logs/prod.log) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php:4987 Stack trace: #0 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4931): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4856): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5056): Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler->handleBatch(Array) #3 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5361): Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array) #4 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/cl in /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 4987
```

Comment: are you able to access the command line on the server?

Comment: I don't know how, the hosting provides me with directadmin though

Comment: unless you are able to change permissions/ownership on directories and access error logs, it is not possible to assist with this

Comment: I can edit the permissions with filezilla

Comment: what is the error in the logs?

Comment: your symfony logs don't have the proper permissions.  You need to allow the web user access to write to the logs.

Comment: I did everything from scratch again and now everything is working

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities wihout more case detail.

- I bet for lack of permissions in log and cache folder
- check the server log, or symfony logs

Joan

Comment: I have set the permission for cache and log on 777. Will check the logs later on and let it know here