# routing is not working properly on production (symfony)

Tags: symfony, routes

I just uploaded symfony site to the server but it's routing is not working. 
my app/config/routing.yml is look like this

```
    acme_data:
        resource: "@AcmeDataBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        host:   "etc.makemeright.in"
        prefix:   /

    acme_blog:
        resource: "@AcmeBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        host:   "makemeright.in"
        prefix:   /

    app:
        resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
        type:     annotation
```

But when i hit http://www.makemeright.in  it call a Controller in AppBundle while it should be calling according to @AcmeBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml".

Maybe it's not recognizing host or something else.

This project is working fine on my local system. what I am doing wrong ??
please help.

I followed [Steps to move Symfony 2 project to hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462220/steps-to-move-symfony-2-project-to-hosting) to upload my site to server.

Comment: Is there a reason that you use "makemeright.in" rather than "www.makemeright.in" in the acme_blog route, since "www.makemeright.in" is the site being browsed?

Comment: It is standard way to write it. But i also tried with www an http also. But no change in result.

Comment: Thanks cilefen. may be i tried only with http . its working fine with www. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are browsing the app at "www.makemeright.in", then the file should be:

```
acme_data:
    resource: "@AcmeDataBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:   "etc.makemeright.in"
    prefix:   /

acme_blog:
    resource: "@AcmeBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:   "www.makemeright.in"
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```